# Calculating time to earn a specific amount as interest

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot figure out the approach to this as the principle amount shall change after every year(if calculated annually, which shall be the easiest). Eventual goal is to calculate exact number of years, months and days to earn say 150000 as interest on a deposit of 1000000 at an interest rate of say 6.5%. I have tried but cannot seem to figure out how to increment the year/month/day in the loop. I don't mind if this is down voted because I have not posted any code(Well, they are wrong). This is not as simple as it might seem to beginners here.

Comment: This is more a maths question than a python question, once you understand the mathmatics of it coding it in python will be easy

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Hey! Thanks for the comment. Will do.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle The interest calculation is easy. Adding it to the principal consecutively is also easy. Incrementing time in the same loop is difficult, then to divide year into months and days is another thing, haven't even figured out annual one yet. This would require multiple functions, I suppose.

Comment: I am just going to eat dinner then i will have a look at the calulation and if the question is still unanswered i would post something. Also is this to be accurate like for example taking into account leap years or just assume a year is 365 days

Comment: @ChrisDoyle No, No leap years or anything. Given the lock down I gave this problem to myself to see if I can do it, it is not a job or anything. to earn 4,00,000 on a deposit of 25,00,000 at 8% should take 22 months..that's what I was looking for. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pure maths question. Compound interest is calculated as follows:

*P<sub>total</sub>* = *P<sub>initial</sub>**(1+*rate*/100)<sup>*time*</sup>

where *P<sub>total</sub>* is the new *total*. *rate* is usually given in percentages so divide by 100; *time* is in years. You are interested in the difference, though, so use

*interest* = *P<sub>initial</sub>**(1+*rate*/100)<sup>*time*</sup> – *P<sub>initial</sub>*

instead, which is in Python:

```py
def compound_interest(P,rate,time):
    interest = P*(1+rate/100)**time - P
    return interest
```

A basic inversion of this to yield *time*, given *P*, *r*, and *target* instead, is

*time* = log((*target*+*P<sub>initial</sub>*)/*P<sub>initial</sub>*)/log(1+*rate*/100)

and this will immediately return the number of years. Converting the fraction to days is simple – an average year has 365.25 days – but for *months* you'll have to approximate.

At the bottom, the result is fed back into the standard compound interest formula to show it indeed returns the expected yield.

```py
import math

def reverse_compound_interest(P,rate,target):
    time = math.log((target+P)/P)/math.log(1+rate/100)
    return time

timespan = reverse_compound_interest(2500000, 6.5, 400000)
print ('time in years',timespan)
years = math.floor(timespan)
months = math.floor(12*(timespan - years))
days = math.floor(365.25*(timespan - years - months/12))

print (years,'y',months,'m',days,'d')

print (compound_interest(2500000, 6.5, timespan))
```

will output

```
time in years 2.356815854829652
2 y 4 m 8 d
400000.0
```

Can we do better? Yes. `datetime` allows arbitrary numbers added to the current date, so assuming you start earning *today* (***now***), you can immediately get your date of $$$:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

# ... original script here ...

timespan *= 31556926 # the number of seconds in a year
print ('time in seconds',timespan)
print (datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=timespan))
```

which shows for me (your target date will differ):

```
time in years 2.356815854829652
time in seconds 74373863.52648607
2022-08-08 17:02:54.819492
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```py
def how_long_till_i_am_rich(investment, profit_goal, interest_rate):
    profit = 0
    days = 0
    daily_interest = interest_rate / 100 / 365
    while profit < profit_goal:
        days += 1
        profit += (investment + profit) * daily_interest
    years = days // 365
    months = days % 365 // 30
    days = days - (months * 30) - (years * 365)
    return years, months, days


years, months, days = how_long_till_i_am_rich(2500000, 400000, 8)
print(f"It would take {years} years, {months} months, and {days} days")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
It would take 1 years, 10 months, and 13 days
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Kept it simple.